# JSON instead of CSV for bubble chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm using bubble chart which takes input from csv file, is there a way to use JSON instead?

Here is the Problem url:
http://ec2-54-198-148-171.compute-1.amazonaws.com/webapp/provider-view

Problem Code:

```
d3.csv(flare.csv, function(d) {

//console.log(d);
  d.value = +d.value;
   d.seq = +d.seq;
  if (d.value) return d;
}, function(error, classes) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var root = d3.hierarchy({children: classes})
      .sum(function(d) { return d.value; })
      .each(function(d) {
        if (id = d.data.id) {
          var id,seq, i = id.lastIndexOf(".");
          d.id = id;//console.log(i + "  " + id);
          d.package = id.slice(0, i);//console.log(d.package);
          d.class = id.slice(i + 1);
          d.seq = d.data.seq;
        }
      });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(pack(root).leaves())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
      if(d.seq==1){
      d.x = d.x - 100;
          d.y = d.y + 20;
       return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      }else{
      d.x = d.x + 500;
            d.y = d.y + 20;
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
       }      });

  node.append("circle")

      .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { d.r = parseInt(d.r)-5; return d.r; })
      .attr("onclick",function(d) { return "demo('" +d.id + "',"+ d.seq+","+ (d.x+d.r+111)+","+ (d.y+100-30)+");"; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { //console.log(d.seq);
      if(d.seq==1){
       return "url(#gradient1)";
      }else{
      return "#773F9B";
       }    

      });

  node.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", function(d) { return "clip-" + d.id; })
    .append("use")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "#" + d.id; });

  node.append("div")
        .attr("id","tooltip")
       .attr("style","width:100px;height:10px;background-color:gray;z-index:1000");

});
```

Sample csv :

```
id,value,seq
demo11,100,1
demo12,200,1
demo13,300,1
demo14,400,1
demo15,500,1
demo16,600,1
demo17,600,1
demo21,50,2
demo22,100,2
demo23,150,2
demo24,200,2
demo25,250,2
demo26,300,2
demo27,350,2
```

Comment: use d3.json instead of d3.csv and adapt accordingly.

Comment: A quick "csv to json" search will show plenty of results where you candrop a CSV in and produce a json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: yes.

The long answer: to change the data from a csv file to a json file, it's not simply a matter of changing `d3.csv` for `d3.json`. That's necessary, of course, as @RobertLongson said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243600/json-instead-of-csv-for-bubble-chart/41243715#comment69686683_41243600). But, besides that, you'll have to understand how `d3.csv` creates an array of objects with your CSV, since you need to create your JSON mimicking that array.

So, given your CSV, this is how `d3.csv` creates an array of objects:

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

```css
pre {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">id,value,seq
demo11,100,1
demo12,200,1
demo13,300,1
demo14,400,1
demo15,500,1
demo16,600,1
demo17,600,1
demo21,50,2
demo22,100,2
demo23,150,2
demo24,200,2
demo25,250,2
demo26,300,2
demo27,350,2</pre>
```

That being said, to change your data from CSV to JSON (without doing any further change in the code), your JSON need to have exactly this structure:

```
[{
    "id": "demo11",
    "value": "100",
    "seq": "1"
}, {
    "id": "demo12",
    "value": "200",
    "seq": "1"
}, {
    "id": "demo13",
    "value": "300",
    "seq": "1"
}, {
    "id": "demo14",
    "value": "400",
    "seq": "1"
}, {
    "id": "demo15",
    "value": "500",
    "seq": "1"
}, {
    "id": "demo16",
    "value": "600",
    "seq": "1"
}, {
    "id": "demo17",
    "value": "600",
    "seq": "1"
}, {
    "id": "demo21",
    "value": "50",
    "seq": "2"
}, {
    "id": "demo22",
    "value": "100",
    "seq": "2"
}, {
    "id": "demo23",
    "value": "150",
    "seq": "2"
}, {
    "id": "demo24",
    "value": "200",
    "seq": "2"
}, {
    "id": "demo25",
    "value": "250",
    "seq": "2"
}, {
    "id": "demo26",
    "value": "300",
    "seq": "2"
}, {
    "id": "demo27",
    "value": "350",
    "seq": "2"
}]
```