# how to parse json data in d3 multi line charts designed in CSV

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955 , the link has d3 graph for external TSV file, when I modify the d3 TSV library to JSON and parse the data, there is an error in parsing JSON through the graph. 
My JSON data for the same is

```
[{"date": "1-May-12", "close": 10, "open": 15},{"date": "30-Apr-12", "close": 12, "open": 18},{"date": "27-Apr-12", "close": 05, "open": 20},{"date": "26-Apr-12", "close": 01, "open": 15}]
```

I am calling the json file like this, with the same variable names

```
d3.json("data.json", type, function(error, data) { if (error) throw error;...
```

Error is "JSON Parse error: Expected '}'"

Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. "*

Comment: I think you have leading zeros for close property hence the JSON parse is failing. Just remove the leading zero's.

Comment: Please provide more information about your type function?

Comment: Just a tip: `d3.json` does **not** accept a type (or accessor, or row) function. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42475856/5768908

Comment: And another tip, for free: with or without a type function, the code you linked will **never** work with the JSON you copy/pasted.

Comment: Like mentioned in the comment by @GerardoFurtado, please remove the type function. Also, the data returned is not a proper JSON that's why d3.json is failing to parse it. Make sure you have proper JSON structure returned. Like I already mentioned, your close property has leading zero's. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Gerardo why would it not work with this json? Is it just because of the leading zeros?

Comment: @megadarkfriend Nope, I never said that. Even if that's a valid JSON (I didn't check), it will not fix the problem. To understand the real problem, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41243715/5768908

Comment: @Gerardo it is the same format though as you wrote in your answer. The only difference I see is that OP used ints instead of strings. That being said, that was an interesting read, thanks!

Comment: @megadarkfriend thanks, but unfortunately "Interesting" is not good enough for S.O. though... for instance, it received less upvotes than this question. Well, that was just me venting. Back to the code: look at the TSV file **in the code OP linked** and compare with his JSON. It's completely different.